# What note would be used to fit 4 notes in a 5/8 time signature

Tags: notation, time-signatures, tuplet

What note represents 1.25 beats. Or in other words 4 notes in 5/8 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no individual symbol representing 1.25 beats. To do it in 5/8 time, one would either use:

- eighth note (1 beat) tied to a 32nd note (.25 beats)
- a sixteenth (.5 beats) tied to a dotted sixteenth (.75 beats) (or vice versa)
- a four-tuplet

[image: Examples of three notation options]

The first solution is better for a single note; the second might be easier for a reader uncomfortable with tuplets; but the last solution works better for the title problem of four equal divisions of five beats.

Comment: There's also another option: it's still a bit obscure, but it keeps a consistent reference of the pulse and it's also the commonly accepted simplification (and explanation) of the actual "subdivision": https://i.stack.imgur.com/z258B.png